# In Apple iCloud terminology, what are "graveyard", "tombstone", "quarantine", and "namespace"?

Tags: macos, sync, icloud

My Mac (MacOS Catalina 10.15 Beta) fails to download files from iCloud. Tried `rm -rf` everything related to iCloud, reboot, but it still gets stuck in the middle of download.

Since brute force does not work, I decided to debug issues, and see lots of iCloud errors in the logs related to "graveyard", "tombstone", "quarantine", "namespace" etc. Cannot find any documentation on these. Any ideas?

Examples of errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to move <private> to graveyard
[ERROR] Cannot create tombstone for the object <private>
[ERROR] Unable to set quarantine {NSDescription=<private>}
```

Also I hate these `<private>` things in the log that replace real file names. Any way to turn off replacement of filenames to `<private>` tags in Catalina?